# Regular expression in Tcl parses only 1st digit from the number

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to parse out n-digit number from an output, my regular expression parses only the 1st digit.

```
regexp "$header(?:.|\\n)*?$detail\\s+:\\s(\\d+)" $output match value
```

I need it this way as multiple "headers" contains my "detail".
I call this regexp in tcl script.
e.g.

```
set header "Header1"
set detail "Detail1"
```

But regexp returns in $value only 2 instead of 25

Can please anybody help with this?

Thank you

example of output:

```
Header1
Detail1   : 25
Detail2   : 5     

Header2
Detail1   : 18
Detail2   : 200
```

In case I have just simple output(without multiple headers), then regular expression

```
regexp "$detail\\s+:\\s(\\d+)" $output match value
```

returns correctly n-digit number

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

- You do not need `(?:.|\n)` in TCL regex, `.` already matches line breaks, too.
- The `*?` sets the greediness of all quantifiers in the regex to lazy, so `\d+` later acts as if it were `\d+?` and thus only grabs a single digit at the end of the pattern.

You can use

```
regexp {header.*?detail\s*:\s*(\d+)(?:\D|$)} $output match value
```

or - *only* if there is always a non-word character or end of string to the right of the number:

```
regexp {header.*?detail\s*:\s*(\d+)\y} $output match value
```

The `(?:\D|$)` sets a right-hand digit boundary and  `\y` sets a word boundary (since we do not know what kind of context there might be to the right of the number, the digit boundary is a safer solution).

See the [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/KkotOr).

Comment: Thank you very much, regexp {header.*?detail\s*:\s*(\d+)\y} $output match value   works perfectly! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Alex Yes, the point is that the lazy patterns at the end of the regex need to have an explicit boundary, so in my opinion, if you need to capture all digits you need to match them until a non-digit (`\D`) or end of string (`$`).

Comment: I substituted constants with variables  to use in my tcl script  and it works great!                                      
 regexp "$opts(pattern).*?$opts(detail)\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)(?:\\D|$)" $output match value